# Has anyone faced issues with nativescript plugin calling android native code?

Tags: nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

I am working on a nativescript plugin around a native Android SDK.
I have to subclass a native android abstract class
Given below is the way I did this: -

```
declare var com: any;
class MyCallBackClass extends com.xy.ab.mn.somesdk { 
  //com.xy.ab.mn.somesdk is from third party native android library and is an abstract class

  //overridden methods and other variables
} 

class MySDKClass {
  myCallBack: any; 
  constructor() {
     this.myCallBack = new MyCallBackClass()
  }
}
```

All of this is done in a plugin. When I debug the plugin using the command `npm run plugin.tscwatch`, everything works fine. But when I pack the plugin into a `.tgz` file and use it in my app I am getting the following error: -

When I run the application, I am getting a runtime error as follows: -
`System.err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'ab' of undefined`

If anyone has faced the above issue and have a solution, please help.

Thanks in advance.